# Cannot evaluate f1-score on sklearn cross_val_score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, metrics

I'm working on a multiclass classification problem.

I can get f1 scores when using train_test_split and then getting the classification report as shown below:

```
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, y_data,test_size=0.3, random_state = 1, stratify=y_data)
    knn_clf=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors)
    knn_clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
    ypred=knn_clf.predict(X_test) #These are the predicted output values
    print(classification_report(y_test, ypred))
```

However, due to the size of the dataset cross-validation is more applicable. The problem is that I cannot get the f1 scores using the cross-validation method. Without the addition of the f1 the cross-validation looks like this:

```
    knn_cv = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors)
    cv_scores = cross_val_score(knn_cv, data, y_data, cv=3)

    #print each cv score (accuracy) and average them
    print("cv_scores: ", cv_scores)
    print('cv_scores mean:{}'.format(np.mean(cv_scores)))
```

Which outputs:
cv_scores:  [0.83333333 1.         1.        ]
cv_scores mean:0.9444444444444445

When I add in F1 as follows:

```
print(cross_val_score(knn_cv, data, y_data, scoring="f1", cv = 3))
```

It outputs:
[nan nan nan]
cv_scores:  [nan nan nan]
cv_scores mean:nan

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:
The error is raises is:
ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted'].

However when running:

```
print(cross_val_score(knn_cv, data, y_data, average ='weighted', scoring='f1', cv = 3, error_score="raise"))
```

The returned error is:
TypeError: cross_val_score() got an unexpected keyword argument 'average'

which occurs for all None, 'micro', 'macro', and 'weighted'

Comment: Add `error_score="raise"` to the `cross_val_score` and add the resulting error traceback to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message's reference to the `average` argument is for the function `f1_score`. When specifying the scorer for `cross_val_score` as a string, the correct specification is `scoring="f1_weighted"` etc.; see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values.